# Google Reflections slowed by scanning many unnecessary files

Tags: java

I am using Google Reflections 0.9.10 to scan an external jar file (using a URLClassLoader) and my main class of my application, which is called Volts of Doom, (using `ClassName.getClassLoader()`)

I am searching for a custom annotation, `@Mod`, so I do not want to try to search for it in files such as:
`could not scan file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in url file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar` because it is slowing down the loading cycle a lot

I assume that this is being scanned because it is on my Maven classpath, as it should be because I use it as a dependancy.

In this case, they are not java files, but resources, so they do not impact the speed, as they are not being scanned (as it says), but to me, this means that it is still searching in those files. If it does find java files there, those *will* impact the loading speed.

How do I prevent Reflections from scanning these external jar files?

Thus far, I have tried using:

```java
new FilterBuilder().excludePackage("java")
.excludePackage("org.reflections")
.excludePackage("com.google")
.excludePackage("com.sun")
```

...however this does not solve the issue.

A sample of my logs:

```
11:58:09.005 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - going to scan these urls:
file:/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/zapbyte/voltsofdoom/resources/mods/test3.jar
file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/3.2.3/lwjgl-3.2.3-natives-windows.jar
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
file:/C:/Users/admin/OneDrive/Desktop/Java/VoltsOfDoom/voltsofdoomparent/voltsofdoom/target/classes/
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-openal/3.2.3/lwjgl-openal-3.2.3.jar
file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-glfw/3.2.3/lwjgl-glfw-3.2.3-natives-windows.jar

... etc for more files


11:58:09.065 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file .classpath in url file:/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/zapbyte/voltsofdoom/resources/mods/test3.jar with scanner SubTypesScanner
11:58:09.065 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file .classpath in url file:/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/zapbyte/voltsofdoom/resources/mods/test3.jar with scanner MethodAnnotationsScanner

^^ This is good: they are in the jar I want to scan

11:58:09.080 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in url file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/3.2.3/lwjgl-3.2.3-natives-windows.jar with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
11:58:09.080 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in url file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/3.2.3/lwjgl-3.2.3-natives-windows.jar with scanner SubTypesScanner

^^ This is not, because they are extraneous.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have patched the issue with this `FilterBuilder`:

```
public static FilterBuilder defaultFilterBuilder() {
return new FilterBuilder()//
    // Exclude sources
    .excludePackage("java")//
    .excludePackage("lib/").exclude("lib/")//
    .excludePackage("lib.").exclude("lib.")//
    .excludePackage("resources/").exclude("resources/")//
    .excludePackage("resources.").exclude("resources.")//
    .excludePackage("META-INF/").exclude("META-INF/")//
    .excludePackage("META-INF.").exclude("META-INF.")//
    .excludePackage("org.reflections").excludePackage("org/reflections")//
    .excludePackage("com.google").excludePackage("com/google")//
    .excludePackage("org.lwjgl").excludePackage("org/lwjgl")//
    .excludePackage("ch.qos").excludePackage("ch/qos")//
    .excludePackage("edu.umd").excludePackage("edu/umd")//
    .excludePackage("jdk.nashorn").excludePackage("jdk/nashorn")//
    .excludePackage("jdk.internal").excludePackage("jdk/internal")//
    .excludePackage("windows.x64").excludePackage("windows/x64")//
    .excludePackage("net.jcip").excludePackage("net/jcip")//
    .excludePackage("com.sun").excludePackage("com/sun")//
    .excludePackage("sun.text").excludePackage("sun/text")//

    // Exclude resources
    .excludePackage("image/").exclude("image/")//
    .excludePackage("image.").exclude("image.")//
    .excludePackage("font/").exclude("font/")//
    .excludePackage("font.").exclude("font.")//
;
```

}

Which excludes every package which was logged as slowing the process, and has cut the average log size during loading from 2.5MB to 91KB.

According to [this comment on the org.reflections GitHub repository](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/131#issuecomment-366660692) you need to exclude both “org.google” and “org/google” to catch everything.